# Drawing line attached to two shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes

**NOTE: I'm not looking for a XAML Solution.**

I'm having trouble figuring out how to attach a line to two shapes. The best visible representation of what I'm looking for would be two balls attached to both ends of a straight stick. The problem I'm having is on how to display the line which is dependent on both the positions of ball01's and ball02's center position. As of now, both balls display as I want it, but when ball02 moves away from ball01 (ball02 starts off centered on ball01), the line is not visible.

```
ball01 = new Ellipse() { Height = BIG_SIZE, Width = BIG_SIZE };     
ball01.Fill = baseBrush;
ball01.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
setBall01X(e.GetPosition(canvas).X - (BIG_SIZE / 2));
setBall01Y(e.GetPosition(canvas).Y - (BIG_SIZE / 2));
Canvas.SetLeft(ball01, getBall01X());
Canvas.SetTop(ball01, getBall01Y()); 
canvas.Children.Add(ball01);

ball02 = new Ellipse() { Height = SMALL_SIZE, Width = SMALL_SIZE };
ball02.Fill = childBrush;
ball02.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
setBall02X(e.GetPosition(canvas).X - (SMALL_SIZE / 2));
setBall02Y(e.GetPosition(canvas).Y - (SMALL_SIZE / 2));
Canvas.SetLeft(ball02, getBall02X());
Canvas.SetTop(ball02, getBall02Y());
canvas.Children.Add(ball02);

// line's X's and Y's are to point to the center of both balls
// Regardless of where the balls move.
line01 = new Line() 
{
    X1 = getBall01X() + (BIG_SIZE / 2),
    Y1 = getBall01Y() + (BIG_SIZE / 2),
    X2 = getBall02X() + (SMALL_SIZE / 2),
    Y2 = getBall02Y() + (SMALL_SIZE / 2)
};


line01.Fill = baseBrush;
line01.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
line01.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
line01.StrokeThickness = 2;
// Canvas.Set???
canvas.Children.Add(line01);
```

Comment: That was highly rude and inappropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Ellipse` and `Line` controls and positioning them by `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` you may prefer to use three `Path` controls with appropriate geometries. Especially the `EllipseGeometry` provides far easier handling of its center point, compared to an `Ellipse` control.

```
private EllipseGeometry ball1Geometry = new EllipseGeometry();
private EllipseGeometry ball2Geometry = new EllipseGeometry();
private LineGeometry lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    canvas.Children.Add(new Path
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        Data = ball1Geometry
    });

    canvas.Children.Add(new Path
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        Data = ball2Geometry
    });

    canvas.Children.Add(new Path
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        Data = lineGeometry
    });
}

...

private void UpdateDrawing(
    Point ball1Position, double ball1Radius,
    Point ball2Position, double ball2Radius)
{
    ball1Geometry.RadiusX = ball1Radius;
    ball1Geometry.RadiusY = ball1Radius;
    ball1Geometry.Center = ball1Position;

    ball2Geometry.RadiusX = ball2Radius;
    ball2Geometry.RadiusY = ball2Radius;
    ball2Geometry.Center = ball2Position;

    lineGeometry.StartPoint = ball1Position;
    lineGeometry.EndPoint = ball2Position;
}
```

---

Then you may also prefer to do it the WPF way and create the Paths in XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="ball1Geometry"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="ball2Geometry"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry x:Name="lineGeometry"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd better draw in two steps :
1) add the 3 figures and store them (when building your window).
2) update the coordinates in an animating loop.
It will be faster / handier than clearing/filling the canvas on each frame.

For your line issue : hook it on circle 1's center, and have it go to circle 2's center :

```
  // new line coordinates :
  X1 = Y1 = 0
  X2 = Balle02X - Balle01X + ( SMALL_SIZE / 2 )
  Y2 = Balle02Y - Balle01Y + ( SMALL_SIZE / 2 )
  Canvas.SetTop ( line01, Balle01X + (BIG_SIZE / 2) )
  Canvas.SetLeft( line01, Balle01Y + (BIG_SIZE / 2) )
```